# Who is the kid on Preview app icon?

Tags: applications, preview

[image]

- Who's this kid?

btw, I am also sure that, he's now not that much innocent, he grew up.

Its also noticeable that with release of `Yosemite`, the Preview app icon get changed.

Comment: I see no practical problem to be solved here per the [help]. Discussion and wiki/trivia are best for other sites or chat if you want to discuss things of similar vein or this question in specific. Specifically "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Answer (score 1):

Apple often uses employee's photos for things like this.

When filling iPhoto with content for on stage demos and later demos in their stores Apple will often request photos from their employees, through an open submission contest.  Obviously not every photo gets used but more often than not the family photos you're seeing are shared from an employee somewhere within Apple.  I've tried to find some of the old articles that outlined this process but they've either been buried away or removed at the request of Apple.

Knowing that, my best guess is this was a son, nephew, grandson, etc of an Apple employee around the time that Apple was looking to change the Preview icon.

Hardly a definite answer (we still don't know who he is) but it might be the closest we get.

Answer (score 0):

Using [google image search](https://www.google.fr/search?safe=off&tbs=simg%3aCAESmgEalwELEKjU2AQaBggBCBcIPQwLELCMpwgaPAo6CAISFMkdvhzZJYIZohnWHs4e4hWmEcYdGiAyxV5KToY-BHwGGdGMYTyalPewK47RszaNg18-lMrsDgwLEI6u_1ggaCgoICAESBAMwq-8MCxCd7cEJGicKCgoIdmFjYXRpb24KBwoFc21pbGUKBQoDYm95CgkKB3dlYXRoZXIM&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=eWSYU4uSFvSe0wXQuIDIBA&ved=0CCkQsw4&biw=1680&bih=913), the only result is this [twitter account](https://twitter.com/shangcesuo) but it doesn't seems to be him.

Comment: That user asking for, "Hows my new avatar?" means this isn't he.